# Редирект url на нижний регистр

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Подскажите, как корректно настроить через файл .htaccess 301 редирект на нижний регистр ссылок в таком рЕгИсТре?
Спасибо!

Comment: Это делается через [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int), но это не лучший вариант по нагрузке, т.к. проверяется каждый запрос. Лучший вариант - это прописать canonical URL.

Comment: Я попробовал два варианта перенаправление на нижний регист через php

 1. Ложит север и отдает 500 при изменении регистра
`$url = mb_strtolower(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'UTF-8') ;
    if(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != $url) {
     // Выполняем редирект 301
     header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url, true, 301) ;
    }
 end`

 2. Зацикливает 301

`$lowerURI=strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!=$lowerURI)
  {
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("location:http//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
   .$lowerURI);
   exit();
  }`

Comment: имена файлов и директорий сами по себе могут иметь разный регистр, поэтому нереально. Пропишите в странице `<link rel="canonical" href="http://site.ru/правильный_url" />`

Answer (score 8):

На одном из проектов ставил в htaccess 2 правило [отсюда, но сейчас опробовал и первый вариант](http://proadminz.ru/htaccess-redirekt-url-v-nizhniy-registr/):

---

Добавляем в файл виртуального хоста запись:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

После чего, добавляем следующие записи в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

Второй вариант подобный правил:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Способ 2 — наиболее громоздкий, но не требующий доступа к настройкам Apache.
Достаточно добавить правила в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: а как это вариант ведет себя с php-fpm ?

Comment: Вариант с кучей RewriteRule - как убрать редирект, если это файл?

Comment: Поддерживаю вопрос @Skywave. В том случае, если на конце у нас идет файл с именем к примеру Tiny.png. Как исключить такой вариант из правила? Последний вариант у меня на 2-ух серверах повел по разному. На 1-ом всё норм, на 2-ом сайт перестал отрываться через некоторое время и выдавал 503 ошибку

Answer (score 7):

Решение через PHP:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
            strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), true, 301);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
    header('Location: //'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), true, 301);
    exit();
}
```

Лучше использовать "//" после Location вместо "http://". Это сделает выбор протокола автоматическим и предотвратит от двойной переадресации, если на сервере она настроена с http на https.