# Apache2 301 redirect: ссылки верхнего регистра перенаправить на ссылки нижнего регистра

Tags: apache2

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu).

Друзья как можно на уровне htaccess ссылки где параметры содержать верхний регистр перенаправить (301 redirect) на те же ссылки в нижнем регистре ?

Пытаюсь реализовать следующим образом:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Но пока что не получается.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425398/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-url-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему вам это надо делать именно на уровне .htaccess?

Я неоднократно сталкивался с тем, что попытка преобразования регистров через .htaccess приводила к тому, что соответствующий процесс Apache выедал всю память до которой мог дотянуться. Уж не знаю с чем это связано было, но такую проблему я и сам наблюдал и в Сети описания попадались.

В качестве альтернативы я встречал такой довольно шустрый метод, который гораздо менее затратен по памяти: https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2012/11/force-lowercase-urls-rewrite-php/

Его суть в том, что запросы, содержащие верхний регистр и не являющиеся файлом на диске, перенаправляются на специальный PHP скрипт:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# force url to lowercase if upper case is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
# ensure it is not a file on the drive first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

А сам файл содержит такой код:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'];
    unset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url']);
    $params = http_build_query($_GET);
    if(strlen($params)) {
        $params = '?' . $params;
    }
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . strtolower($url) . $params, true, 301);
    exit;
}
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die('Unable to convert the URL to lowercase. You must supply a URL to work upon.');
```

Так же можете попробовать использовать модуль [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html). Как сказано в документации: `"If, after scanning the directory, ... only one document is found that "almost" matches the request, then it is returned in the form of a redirection response"`. Если вам необходимо лишь преобразование регистра - включите директиву `CheckCaseOnly on`.

Answer (score 2):

---

Добавляем в файл виртуального хоста запись:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

После чего, добавляем следующие записи в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

Второй вариант подобный правил:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Способ 2 — наиболее громоздкий, но не требующий доступа к настройкам Apache.
Достаточно добавить правила в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```