# Не учитывать регистр в ссылках?

Tags: php, symfony2

Сайт на Symfony 2, при переходе по ссылке
https://mysite.com/newpizza/Hot/Tasty/ получаю 501 ошибку, а если
https://mysite.com/newpizza/hot/tasty/, то страница отображается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста:
 1. Как автоматически исправлять все большие буквы на маленькие?
 2. Как сделать редирект на страницу с маленькими буквами?

Comment: Не знаю, есть ли какое-то нативное решение для вашего фреймворка, но если использовать фреймворконезависимые способы, то ответы (через htaccess и через php) можно найти [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425398/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-url-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80).

Comment: Перейти на файловую систему, в которой регистр символов игнорируется - не предлагать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует несколько способов:

1. Настроить веб-сервер, чтобы он это делал. Тут конфиг будет зависеть от веб-сервера и можно задать отдельный вопрос, о том, как настроить конкретный сервер на редиректы или принятие запросов в зависимости от регистра.
2. Можно провести настройку на уровне приложения. Это может пригодиться в случаях, когда не хочется жертвовать чувствительностью к регистру сразу во всех роутах.

Так как вопрос касается именно фреймворка Symfony, рассмотрим пример конфигурации роутов для отображения одной страницы по роутам независимо от регистра:

```
new_pizza:
    pattern:   /{category1}/{category2}
    defaults:  { _controller: Bundle:Controller:Action }
    requirements:
        category1:  (?i:[^/]+)
        category2:  (?i:[^/]+)
```

Как видно в примере, конфигурация роута позволяет использовать стандартный синтаксис RegExp, чтобы определить, будет ли параметр чувствителен к регистру или нет.

Answer (score 1):

поидее надо копать в сторону настроек твоего веб-сервера, если это Apache то поискать RewriteRule для твоего случая, mod_rewrite